# product image getting bigger as the gallery image number increases magento 2 and vise versa after adding bootstrap css (cdn)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, cdn, gallery-image

product image getting bigger as the gallery image number increases magento 2 and vise Versa after adding bootstrap css (cdn)
How to make the product image load in big size no matter what number is the product gallery number??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmi79.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this problem caused by some bootstrap scss files such _reboot.scss and _boot.scss I have added 

 
to default_head_blocks.xml but it doesn't work
the question is how to remove _reboot.scss and _boot.scss?
or can I override these two files to them (neutral) not affect any tag?

Answer (score 0):

the solution

```
.media {
  display: block;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.media-body {
  flex: 1;
}


*,
*::before,
*::after {
box-sizing: initial; // 1
}
```